# boost::enable_if with two conditions

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, c++03

As you can see in the following example, I currently use a `boost::enable_if` as return value of an allocation function. The goal is to avoid a compilation error for abstract types:

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>,T*>::type no_abstract_new()
{
  assert(false);
  return 0;
}

template <typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>,T*>::type no_abstract_new()
{
  return new T;
}
```

Now, I also want to exclude classes inheriting from a own class named `has_no_default_constructor`. **Is there a way to have a `or` in the condition of `boost::enable_if` ?** Somthing like this uncorrect code:

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>
                       || boost::is_base_of<has_no_default_constructor,T>,T*>::type default_constructor_new()
{
  assert(false);
  return 0;
}

template <typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_abstract<T>
                        || boost::is_base_of<has_no_default_constructor,T>,T*>::type default_constructor_new()
{
  return new T;
}
```

**Or have I to implement a own class of trait doing the job ?** (I'm totally lost for this. I understand the idea, but I feel enable to do it myself)

Notes:

- I don't use C++11 for compatibility reason
- I know `has_default_constructor` exists in C++11, but not before C++11
- `boost::has_default_constructor` exists but is only an alias of `boost::has_trivial_constructor` if compiled without C++11

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: @user463035818 : you're right. Looking about that, it works with `boost::enable_if_c`. Thanks. :-)

Comment: With type, it would be `typename boost::enable_if<std::disjunction<boost::is_abstract<T>, boost::is_base_of<has_no_default_constructor,T>>, T*>::type`. In Boost, it seems that [boost::hana::or_](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Logical.html#ga68c00efbeb69339bfa157a78ebdd3f87) does the job.

Comment: Is there any Chance you will ever be able to upgrade, at least part of the library? In that case, make sure to mimic the revised standard-library as close as reasonably possible, so you can later-on drop your own code. Which you probably should put into its own header and namespace, so you can more easily move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also

```
template <bool B, class T = void> struct enable_if_c;
```

note that it takes a `bool` as first parameter not a type. Hence the following should be fine

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_abstract<T>::value
                       || boost::is_base_of<has_no_default_constructor,T>::value
                       ,T*>::type default_constructor_new()
{
  assert(false);
  return 0;
}
```

and similar for the other overload.